# Understanding the javascript THIS keyword

Tags: javascript

I have tried to find an answer to this question by searching the web, but haven't had any luck. Most information is much more complicated then I expected this answer to be, and none actually answered this question.

In this tag:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" name="processform" id="form1" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

What does "this" refer to?

If I was going to replace "this" with a hard-coded reference to the same object what would I replace it with?

Comment: `this` refers to the DOM object of the element with which it is called, ie, the form object. It's `this` form.

Comment: This explains it: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html (you should also read the other articles, they provide a very good explanation of event handling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` will refer to the form node that is being submitted.  You can replace the reference with `document.getElementById('form1')`.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside the "onsubmit" attribute refers to the form itself; when the `validate` function gets called, its first argument is that of the form's DOM element.

For example, consider this possible implementation of `validate`:

```
function validate(form)
{
    alert(form.action); // will display "process.php"
}
```

The good thing about using `this` inside the HTML (as opposed to a fixed name or ID) like this is that you don't have to refer to the form by ID or name.

Comment: Yes, but what about `form`? What would it `alert`, or, `console.log()`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish `form` doesn't alert anything .. I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: [Nothing](http://jsfiddle.net/UhB9W/)? And yes, [`console.log(form)`](http://jsfiddle.net/UhB9W/1/) is more useful.

Comment: And I consider inline event handlers (such as `onsubmit`) as "bad form" compared to the [alternatives](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html).

Comment: My answer only serves to explain how inline references to this work, not the merits of such an approach.